# self not defined when trying to access

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
        self.balance = 0

    def setBalance(self, value):
        self.balance = vale

    def setName(self, name):
        self.name = name

class Main:

    def __init__(self):
        self.people = []

    def addPerson(self,name):
        self.people.append(Person(name))

    def updateBalance(self,balance,index):
        self.people[index].setBalance(50)

    print self.people[0]

main = Main()
main.addPerson("Jack")
main.updateBalance(30,0)
```

I made the following code just to see how objects works with array. But, when I try to run it I get **NameError: name 'self' is not defined**. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong ?

If something is not clear or needs editing then please let me know in the comments before down voting.

Many thanks

Comment: addPerson and updateBalance are trying to use something called "self" which was not passed to them. To the functions, they do not know anything about the object itself unless they specifically receive it.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh thanks. I added it. But it still gives me the error for `print self.people[0]`

Comment: same idea. the print statement has no right to know it should reference the object, and why should it. only functions/methods that have been passed the self keyword should see it. @user8202693

Comment: Delete self from people[0] as I have mentioned in my answer also correct vale to value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a several issues with your code:

- Class methods, need to refer to the class `def ...(self, ...)`
- `print(...)` is a function in Python3 and has to be called from within a method.

The following adjustments make your code work:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.balance = 0

    def setBalance(self, value):
        self.balance = value

    def setName(self, name):
        self.name = name

class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        self.people = []

    def addPerson(self, name):
        self.people.append(Person(name))

    def updateBalance(self, balance, index):
        self.people[index].setBalance(50)
        print("Updating people at index %d" % index)


main = Main()
main.addPerson("Jack")
main.updateBalance(30, 0)

print (main.people[0])
```

Prints:

```
Updating people at index 0
<__main__.Person instance at 0x100d065f0>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should pass `self` as a parameter as well:

```
class Main:

    def __init__(self):
        self.people = []

    def addPerson(self, name):
        self.people.append(Person(name))

    def updateBalance(self, balance,index):
        self.people[index].setBalance(50)

    print people[0] #no need for self if you are calling local variable of class but this will print an empty array
```

---

Also you have type error

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
        self.balance = 0

    def setBalance(self, value):
        self.balance = vale --> not vale but value

    def setName(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

Answer (score 0):

Whereas languages like Java or C++ make the "self"/"this" argument *implicit* in their method definitions, Python makes it *explicit*. So, the method definitions in your `Main` class should look like this:

```
class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        self.people = []

    def addPerson(self, name):
        self.people.append(Person(name))

    def updateBalance(self, balance, index):
        self.people[index].setBalance(50)
```

In effect, what you had before was an `addPerson()` method that accepted *zero* arguments from the caller... and it had *renamed* `self` to `name`, quite unintuitively. Calling the first parameter to a method "self" in Python is only by convention... you could just as easily define `addPerson()` like this:

```
class Main:
    def addPerson(something_other_t_self, name):
        something_other_than_self.people.append(Person(name))
```

...and it would work *exactly* the same.